# Adjustable bar hanger -Maximum load 17Kg/50LB -is the load for vertical or horizontal position?

Tags: electrical

Today I was in Home Depot looking for some electrical boxes and switches and I noticed this thing called [Adjustable bar hanger](https://www.homedepot.ca/product/iberville-adjustable-bar-hanger-11-5-in-18-5-in-/1000185667) which is rated for a 50LB load.

Is this rating for horizontal installation or for vertical installation ?

Answer (score 1):

You typically put this horizontally between joists or trusts so you can center an electrical box.  The 50LB load will be pulling down on the bar hanger.

```
To support an octagonal box between trusts.
Adjustable from 11.5" to 18.5"
Maximum load: 50 Lb (22.70 Kg)
Not intended for ceiling fan
```